# On calculations from $\zeta(3)=\frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin ((n+1)x)\sin (nx)}{(xn^2)^2}dx$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, special-functions, trigonometric-series

I was inspired in a formula that I've found in Internet, page 5 of **Jameson**'s notes about **Frullani integrals**, to ask to Wolfram Alpha this integral $$\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin ax\sin bx}{x^2}dx=\frac{\pi}{4} \left(  \left| a+b \right|- \left| a+b \right|\right), $$
that I presume well known. Then I did the specialisation $a=n+1$, $b=n$ for a fixed integer $n\geq 1$ and after I've multiplied by $\frac{1}{n^4}$ one has if there are no mistakes $$\zeta(3)=\frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin ((n+1)x)\sin (nx)}{(xn^2)^2}dx.$$

My goal is learn more mathematics to encourage myself to study more.

> **Question.** It's possible do more interesting calculations with nice mathematical content to deduce some identity from previous approach/identity? **Thanks in advance.**

**My attempt** was that I know that it is possible to ask to a CAS by the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin ((n+1)x)\sin (nx)}{n^4}$, but I don't know cvery well what's means the result. Also I know that I can do the change $y=xn^2$ of variable in previous integral to get it as $$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin (\frac{n+1}{n^2}y)\sin (\frac{y}{n})}{(yn)^2}dy.$$
But neither I don't know if such change of variables will be useful.

Comment: I hope, that are feasibles more calculations. I believe that it is easily to justify the swap the series and the integral using the Dominated convergence theorem. Thanks.

Comment: Your first expression right hand side vanishes out.

Comment: $$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\prod_{k = 0}^{n}{\sin\left(\, a_{k}x\, \right) \over x} =
{\pi \over 2}\prod_{k = 1}^{n}a_{k}\,,\qquad
a_{k} \in \mathbb{R}\,,\quad a_{0} \geq \sum_{k = 1}^{n}\left\vert\, a_{k}\, \right\vert
$$

Comment: Thanks for your remarks and anser. I study your remarks also to improve my mathematics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\color{#f00}{{2 \over \pi}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\sin\pars{\bracks{n + 1}x}\sin\pars{nx} \over \pars{xn^{2}}^{2}}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] = &\
{2 \over \pi}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n^{4}}\int_{0}^{\infty}
{\sin\pars{\bracks{n + 1}x} \over x}\,{\sin\pars{nx} \over x}\,\dd x
\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{align}
Albeit the integration is an elementary one, it's useful to know that
David Borwein and Jonathan Borwein set the following identity:
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\prod_{k = 0}^{n}{\sin\pars{a_{k}x} \over x}\,\dd x =
{\pi \over 2}\prod_{k = 1}^{n}a_{k}\,,\qquad
a_{k} \in \mathbb{R}\,,k = 0,1,\ldots,n\,,\quad a_{0} \geq \sum_{k = 1}^{n}\verts{a_{k}}
$$
With this identity, \eqref{1} becomes:
$$
\color{#f00}{{2 \over \pi}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\sin\pars{\bracks{n + 1}x}\sin\pars{nx} \over \pars{xn^{2}}^{2}}\,\dd x} =
{2 \over \pi}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n^{4}}\pars{{\pi \over 2}\,n} =
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n^{3}} =
\color{#f00}{\zeta\pars{3}}
$$

> By the way; unfortunately, Jonathan Borwein [died this month](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonathan_Borwein) ( $02$-aug-$2016$ ).

Comment: Very thanks much, then I assumed that my approach isn't right, and your answer can be a tribute to this professor. Wikipedia said that **Borwein is arguably the father of the field known as experimental mathematics**.